# Electron packager does not load icon

Tags: electron, electron-packager

I am trying to set an icon to my electron packager but it does not load.
I tried many ways like...

```
--icon=assets/icon.ico
--icon=./assets/icon.ico
```

but get the error:  Reserved header is not 0 or image type is not icon for 'assets/icon.ico'

and when I tried this

```
--icon=/assets/icon.ico
```

I got an error: WARNING: Could not find icon "/assets/icon.ico", not updating app icon

I tried to put them in double quotes but it does not work

```
--icon="/assets/icon.ico"
--icon="./assets/icon.ico"
--icon="assets/icon.ico"
```

I resized the image from 256x256 px to 32x32 px but it did not make a difference. Does the size affect?

Comment: Hi, can you post your entire `electron-packager` command?

Comment: Here you are >> electron-packager . --version-string.ProductName=\"Resala Naser\" --platform=win32 --arch=x64 --asar=true --prune=true --app-version=1.0 --version-string.FileDescription=CE --icon=/assets/icon.ico

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I needed to add the 'dist' folder to the icon path, so:

```
--icon="dist/assets/icon.ico"
```

Comment: So quotes are required?

Comment: Yes, I believe so

Answer (score 0):

It is worth noting that you need bot a `icon.icns` (mac os) and an `icon.ico` file. That was my issue. I only had an `icon.icns`.